# ASP.Net - How to Uppercase the Month First Letter Result in PT-BR Culture?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using: `<%# Eval("DataCadastro", "{0:MMMM / yyyy}")%>` and result is:

> "março / 2008"

I would like it to be:

> "Março / 2008"

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have options:

1. Cook the data beforehand so it always matches the expected format
2. Add a method to code-behind (e.g., FormatDataCadastro) that will take a field value and convert it to the expected format.  You can call it from the ASPX provided that its accessibility (I think the method may need to be public to do this).
3. Do the conversion in the ASPX file itself.  I don't believe there is a format string specifier to naturally handle this case.  You'll need to grab the first character, up-case it, and then call the Eval statement against field.Substring(1) (i.e., the rest of the string).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need... it was solved this way:

```
protected void BoletinsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        HyperLink docPdf = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("ArquivoHyperLink");
          docPdf.Text = ConvertToTitleCase(docPdf.Text);
    }
}


public static String ConvertToTitleCase(String strParam)
{
    String strTitle = strParam;

    if (strParam.Length > 0)
    {
        strTitle = strParam.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
        strParam = strParam.Substring(1).ToLower();
        String strPrev = "";

        for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < strParam.Length; iIndex++)
        {
            if (iIndex > 1)
            {
                strPrev = strParam.Substring(iIndex - 1, 1);
            }
            if (strPrev.Equals(" ") ||
                strPrev.Equals("\t") ||
                strPrev.Equals("\n") ||
                strPrev.Equals("."))
            {
                strTitle += strParam.Substring(iIndex, 1).ToUpper();
            }
            else
            {
                strTitle += strParam.Substring(iIndex, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return strTitle;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ToTitleCase method.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-br");
var date = new DateTime(2008, 3, 1);
var dateString = date.ToString("MMMM / yyyy", culture);
var titleCased = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dateString);
```